# How to quickly dry the thermals in winters without squeezing or hanging them?

Tags: clothing, winter

The tags on [thermals](https://www.rupaonlinestore.com/product_details.php?8001%20Ladies%20Sleeve%203%2F4&pid=326&catid=13) say:

> Do not squeeze.
>   Do not hang.

So, what would be the quickest way to dry them during winters?

I do not have a dryer.

Comment: Do you mean thermals like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gC0ey.jpg)?

Comment: Yes, like these https://www.rupaonlinestore.com/product_details.php?8001+Ladies+Sleeve+3%2F4&pid=326&catid=13 @Mooseman

Comment: What's wrong with putting them in the clothes dryer?

Comment: I've edited your question for you; important information belongs in the question body, where it's most visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you can't hang them is because the weight of the water, as it moves downwards, and the pegs at the top holding them up, might cause the garment to be stretched or out of shape. Equally, hand squeezing or wringing may alter the shape. After washing, take a large bath towel, lay the garment flat on the towel without over stretching it, roll the towel up with the garment inside, put the towel on a chair or the edge of the bath and sit on it all over. This will extract most of the water, leaving the article slightly damp, though if the garment was very wet initially, you may need to repeat this process with a second towel. Remove the garment and, if you can, drape it over a washing hanging rack or airer to finish drying.

The drawback is, you've now got a damp bath towel to dry.

Comment: Sitting on the wrapped garment sure sounds like squeezing to me.

Comment: Yep, it is - but what they really mean is wringing. After years of doing laundry in my life, I discovered this way works for 'prima donna' clothing - only other option is to drape them soaking wet over a bush or something in the sun

Comment: In addition to the drying rack, I put a small fan underneath it to speed drying. I use a small, portable  washer/spin-dry unit which gets most water out. Afterwards, with the fam/drying rack, it takes about 20 min. to dry.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap the item in a dry towel for a few hours, then repeat with dry towels until its just damp enough to naturally air dry

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of "Do not hang" on clothing...

If you're not allowed to hang them over a chair or shower curtain rod, put them in the dryer. (which is faster anyway)

Comment: Perhaps "do not hang" means don't hang using clothespins or something due to it stretching the material at those points?

Comment: @ZachSaucier That would be my best guess, but I'm working with the info provided by the OP.

Comment: As per OP's comment to the question (and my most recent edit to the question), this is no longer an answer as the OP doesn't have a dryer. Sorry for the confusion, and enjoy your "Fear and Loathing" hat :P